# ¿cual es el código para oledbdataadapter de 64 bits. para codigo en C# y trabajando con MS Access 2016?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy trabajando en una plataforma de 64 bits programación C# en VISUAL STUDIO 2019. Y parece que el siguiente código no funciona para estas características:

```
// Carga una tabla de país o departamento o provincia o municipio
//  ==========================================================================  
    
public static void CargatablaPDPM(string NombreTabla, string nombrecolumna)
{
    dsPDPM = "SELECT * FROM " + NombreTabla + " ORDER BY " + nombrecolumna;
    odaPDPM = new OleDbDataAdapter(dsPDPM, conexregistros);
    odbcPDPM = new OleDbCommandBuilder(odaPDPM);
    dttPDPM = new DataTable();
    odaPDPM.Fill(dttPDPM);
}
```

Comment: public static void CargatablaPDPM(string NombreTabla, string nombrecolumna) { dsPDPM = "SELECT * FROM " + NombreTabla + " ORDER BY " + nombrecolumna; odaPDPM = new OleDbDataAdapter(dsPDPM, conexregistros); odbcPDPM = new OleDbCommandBuilder(odaPDPM); dttPDPM = new DataTable(); odaPDPM.Fill(dttPDPM); }

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, Giovanni. A como está tu pregunta, está dificil responderla. Puedes visitar nuestro [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/) para saber [cómo realizar una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cuando dices *"Parece"*, a qué **exactamente** te refieres? Por qué no funciona? Cuál es el error?